# webpack: npm package dependency not resolved (typescript, angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ts-odatajs/lib/xml.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'xmldom' in 'D:\projects\swiller\querydsl\angular-starter\node_modules\ts-odataj
\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/ts-odatajs/lib/xml.js 183:25-42
 @ ./node_modules/ts-odatajs/index.js
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/home/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src/main.browser.ts
```

My project structure is like:

```
project/src/app
├───home
│   │   home.component.css
│   │   home.component.html
│   │   home.component.spec.ts
│   │   home.component.ts
│   │   home.e2e.ts
│   │   index.ts
```

I've installed `ts-odatajs` npm package: `npm install --save ts-odatajs`. Into `home.component.ts` I've imported some exports from `ts-odatajs`:

```
import { oData } from 'ts-odatajs';
```

I don't quite figure out where's the error. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is the output when I install `ts-odatajs`:

```
PS D:\projects\swiller\querydsl\angular-starter> npm install --save ts-odatajs
angular-starter@7.0.0 D:\projects\swiller\querydsl\angular-starter
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.1.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@5.1.1
+-- ts-odatajs@4.0.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.5.3

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.0.5 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@5.0.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ts-simple-ast@0.97.1 requires a peer of typescript@2.6.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN tsickle@0.24.1 requires a peer of typescript@2.4.2 but none was installed.
```

**EDIT 2**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "ts-odatajs": "^4.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
```

**EDIT 3**

I've just realized that `packages.json` has `xmldom` package as `devDependency`: See [here](https://github.com/tschettler/olingo-odata4-js/blob/master/package.json#L55)

Comment: did you get any UNMET DEPENDENCY error while doing npm install?

Comment: I've just edited the post adding the output.

Comment: guessing here - try updating the package.json file with the shown @angular/compiler & core , then use npm install and ng serve

Comment: I don't quite figure out what should I update. These packages are already in `packages.json` file. See the post. What does `UNMET_PEER_DEPENDENCY` mean?

Comment: I've just realized xmldom is a devDependency of ts-odatajs package. Does it dive you more information about how to solve the problem?

Comment: change the version to 5.1.1 for angular core & compiler in package.json dependencies section and try again

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Apache's original setup for the package dependencies doesn't work well with Angular 5. I had previously tested the package with Angular 4. I think this needs to be listed under dependencies, rather than devDependencies. I'll get this updated in another release.

In the meanwhile, to resolve the issue, you can simply manually install the version of xmldom that it is looking for:

```
npm install xmldom@0.1.19 --save
```

Comment: The ts-odatajs package has been updated to fix this issue.